# Edit the attributes of value in an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input-type-file

I have an input type like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Spoedgevallen" id="redbg" onclick="">
```

The text within "value" is bolded, which may be the case because of a Jquery CSS (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css), which is unreadable to say the least. Basically what I want to do is make the font-weight normal instead of bold.

Page can be found [here.](http://rieke.lt/s/nva)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this css rule:

```
.ui-btn.ui-input-btn.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*jQuery Mobile* is somehow rendering the value of your input field like this:

Before:

```
<input value="Antistollingsmiddelen" id="redbg" onclick="" type="button">
```

and in browser:

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Antistollingsmiddelen
   <input value="Antistollingsmiddelen" id="redbg" onclick="" type="button">
</div>
```

As:

[image]

So in order to prevent your value from getting *bolder* most suitable way is to *wrap* your whole input within a container and write *CSS* related to that container to make text of `<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn...` *normal*.
Instead of altering *jQuery mobile* default classes.

As:

```
<div class="text-wrapper">
    <input type="button" value="Antistollingsmiddelen" id="redbg" onclick="" />
   <!-- Place All your input here -->
</div>
```

and write *CSS* as your browser renders it:

```
.text-wrapper .ui-btn { font-weight: normal;}
```

It will help you to do the trick.